# Cannot open /proc/self/oom_score_adj when I have the right capability

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to set the OOM killer score adjustment for a process, inspired by [`oom_adjust_setup` in OpenSSH's `port_linux.c`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/89a85d724765b6b82e0135ee5a1181fdcccea9c6/openbsd-compat/port-linux.c#L240-L311).  To do that, I open `/proc/self/oom_score_adj`, read the old value, and write a new value.  Obviously, my process needs to be root or have the capability `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` to do that.

I'm getting a result that I can't explain.  When my process doesn't have the capability, I'm able to open that file and read and write values, though the value I write doesn't take effect (fair enough):

```
$ ./a.out 
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE: not effective, not permitted, not inheritable
oom_score_adj value: 0
wrote 5 bytes
oom_score_adj value: 0
```

But when my process *does* have the capability, I *can't even open* the file: it fails with EACCES:

```
$ sudo setcap CAP_SYS_RESOURCE+eip a.out
$ ./a.out 
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE: effective, permitted, not inheritable
failed to open /proc/self/oom_score_adj: Permission denied
```

Why does it do that?  What am I missing?

---

Some further googling led me to [this lkml post by Azat Khuzhin on 20 Oct 2013](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/10/20/29).  Apparently `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` lets you change `oom_score_adj` for any process but yourself.  To change your own score adjustment, you need to combine it with `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` - that is, disable access controls for all files.  (If I wanted that, I would have made this program setuid root.)

So my question is, how can I achieve this *without* `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`?

---

I'm running Ubuntu xenial 16.04.4, kernel version 4.13.0-45-generic.  My problem is similar to but different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26963700/113848): that's about an error on `write`, when not having the capability.

My sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>

void read_value(FILE *fp)
{
  int value;
  rewind(fp);
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &value) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "read failed: %s\n", ferror(fp) ? strerror(errno) : "cannot parse");
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "oom_score_adj value: %d\n", value);
  }
}

void write_value(FILE *fp)
{
  int result;
  rewind(fp);
  result = fprintf(fp, "-1000");
  if (result < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "write failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "wrote %d bytes\n", result);
  }
}

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;

  struct __user_cap_header_struct h;
  struct __user_cap_data_struct d;

  h.version = _LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3;
  h.pid = 0;
  if (0 != capget(&h, &d)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "capget failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  }
  else {
      fprintf(stderr, "CAP_SYS_RESOURCE: %s, %s, %s\n",
          d.effective & (1 << CAP_SYS_RESOURCE) ? "effective" : "not effective",
          d.permitted & (1 << CAP_SYS_RESOURCE) ? "permitted" : "not permitted",
          d.inheritable & (1 << CAP_SYS_RESOURCE) ? "inheritable" : "not inheritable");
  }

  fp = fopen("/proc/self/oom_score_adj", "r+");
  if (!fp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open /proc/self/oom_score_adj: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    read_value(fp);
    write_value(fp);
    read_value(fp);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, after `write_value(fp);`, you need to `rewind(fp);` before you `read_value(fp);` again. Otherwise the file position indicator is as `EOF` for the 2nd read.

Comment: I'm confused.  You cite a source that says you cannot do what you say you want to do.  Do you have a particular reason to doubt that source?

Comment: That mailing list post never got an authoritative answer, as far as I can tell. I guess my question is the same as the one in that post: "Is this works by design, and/or is there another way to do this without suid/root?"

Comment: How about using http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/oom-kill-protect.html ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This one was very interesting to crack, took me a while.

The first real hint was this answer to a different question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364568/how-to-read-the-proc-pid-fd-directory-of-a-process-which-has-a-linux-capabil - just wanted to give the credit.

## The reason it does not work as is

The real reason you get "permission denied" there is files under `/proc/self/` are owned by root if the process has **any** capabilities - it's not about `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` or about `oom_*` files specifically. You can verify this by calling `stat` and using different capabilities. Quoting `man 5 proc`:

> /proc/[pid]
>
> There is a numerical subdirectory for each running process; the subdirectory is named by the process ID.
>
> Each /proc/[pid] subdirectory contains the pseudo-files and directories described below.  These files are normally owned by the effective user and effective group ID of the process.  However, as a  security  measure, the ownership is made root:root if the process's "dumpable" attribute is set to a value other than 1.  This attribute may change for the following reasons:
>
> - The attribute was explicitly set via the prctl(2) PR_SET_DUMPABLE operation.
> - The attribute was reset to the value in the file /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable (described below), for the reasons described in prctl(2).
>
> Resetting the "dumpable" attribute to 1 reverts the ownership of the /proc/[pid]/* files to the process's real UID and real GID.

This already hints to the solution, but first let's dig a little deeper and see that `man prctl`:

> PR_SET_DUMPABLE (since Linux 2.3.20)
>
> Set the state of the "dumpable" flag, which determines whether core dumps are produced for the calling process upon delivery of a signal whose default behavior is to produce a core dump.
>
> In kernels up to and including 2.6.12, arg2 must be either 0 (SUID_DUMP_DISABLE, process is not dumpable) or 1 (SUID_DUMP_USER, process is dumpable).  Between kernels 2.6.13 and 2.6.17, the value 2 was also  permitted, which caused any binary which normally would not be dumped to be dumped readable by root only; for security reasons, this feature has been removed.  (See also the description of /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable in proc(5).)
>
> Normally, this flag is set to 1.  However, it is reset to the current value contained in the file /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable (which by default has the value 0), in the following circumstances:
>
> - The process's effective user or group ID is changed.
> - The process's filesystem user or group ID is changed (see credentials(7)).
> - The process executes (execve(2)) a set-user-ID or set-group-ID program, resulting in a change of either the effective user ID or the effective group ID.
> - **The process executes (execve(2)) a program that has file capabilities (see capabilities(7)), but only if the permitted capabilities gained exceed those already permitted for the process.**
>
> Processes that are not dumpable can not be attached via ptrace(2) PTRACE_ATTACH; see ptrace(2) for further details.
>
> If a process is not dumpable, the ownership of files in the process's /proc/[pid] directory is affected as described in proc(5).

Now it's clear: our process has a capability that the shell used to launch it did not have, thus the dumpable attribute was set to false, thus files under `/proc/self/` are owned by root rather than the current user.

## How to make it work

The fix is as simple as re-setting that dumpable attribute before trying to open the file. Stick the following or something similar before opening the file:

```
prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: I have verified that doing `long dumpable = prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE, 0, 0, 0, 0); prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0);` before opening and writing the `oom_score_adj` file with `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, dumpable, 0, 0, 0);` afterwards, allows a process with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE but no other privileges to set their `oom_score_adj` to any value between OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MIN and OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX, inclusive. Good job!

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer ([dvk already provided the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50953560/1475978) to the stated question), but an extended comment describing the often overlooked, possibly very dangerous side effects, of reducing `/proc/self/oom_score_adj`.

In summary, using `prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0)` will allow a process with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability (conveyed via e.g. filesystem capabilities) to modify the `oom_score_adj` of any other process owned by the same user, including their own.

(By default, a process that has capabilities is not dumpable, so a core dump is not generated even when the process is killed by a signal whose disposition is to generate a core.)

The dangers I'd like to comment on, are how the `oom_score_adj` *range* is inherited, and what it means to change it for processes that create child processes. (Thanks to dvk for some corrections.)

---

The Linux kernel maintains an internal value, `oom_score_adj_min`, for each process.  The user (or the process itself) can modify the `oom_score_adj` to any value between `oom_score_adj_min` and `OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX`. The higher the value, the more likely the process is to be killed.

When a process is created, it will inherit its `oom_score_adj_min` from its parent.  The original parent of all processes, init, has an initial `oom_score_adj_min` of 0.

To reduce the `oom_score_adj` below `oom_score_adj_min`, a process that either has superuser privileges, or has the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE and is dumpable, writes the new score to `/proc/PID/oom_score_adj`.  In this case, `oom_score_adj_min` is also set to the same value.

(You can verify this by examining [fs/proc/base.c:__set_oom_adj()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/base.c) in the Linux kernel; see the assignments to `task->signal->oom_score_adj_min`.)

The problem is that the `oom_score_adj_min` value sticks, except when update by a process that has the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability. (Note: I originally thought that it could not be raised at all, but I was wrong.)

For example, if you have a high-value service daemon that has its `oom_score_adj_min` reduced, running without the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability, increasing the `oom_score_adj` before forking child processes will cause the child processes to inherit the new `oom_score_adj`, but the original `oom_score_adj_min`.  This means such child processes can reduce their `oom_score_adj` to that of their parent service daemon, without any privileges or capabilities.

(Because there are just two thousand and one possible `oom_score_adj` values (`-1000` to `1000`, inclusive), and only a thousand of those reduce the chance of a process to be killed (the negative ones, zero being the default) compared to "default", a nefarious process only needs to do ten or eleven writes to `/proc/self/oom_score_adj` to make the OOM killer avoid it as much as possible, by using a binary search: first, it will try -500. If it succeeds, the `oom_score_adj_min` is between -1000 and -500. If it fails, the `oom_score_adj_min` is between -499 and 1000. By halving the range at each attempt, it can set `oom_score_adj` to the kernel-internal minimum for that process, `oom_score_adj_min`, in ten or eleven writes, depending on what the initial `oom_score_adj` value was.)

---

Of course, there are mitigations and strategies to avoid the inheritance problem.

For example, if you have an important process that the OOM killer should leave alone, that should not create child processes, you should run it using a dedicated user account that has the [`RLIMIT_NPROC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) set to a suitably small value.

If you have a service that creates new child processes, but you want the parent to be less likely to be OOM killed than other processes, and you do not want the children to inherit that, there are two approaches that work.

1. Your service can at startup fork a child process to create further child processes, before it lowers its `oom_score_adj`. This makes the child processes inherit their `oom_score_adj_min` (and `oom_score_adj`) from the process that started the service.
2. Your service can keep `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` in the `CAP_PERMITTED` set, but add or remove it from the `CAP_EFFECTIVE` set as needed.

   When the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` is in the `CAP_EFFECTIVE` set, adjusting `oom_score_adj` also sets the `oom_score_adj_min` to that same value.

   When `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` is not in the `CAP_EFFECTIVE` set, you cannot decrement `oom_score_adj` below the corresponding `oom_score_adj_min`. `oom_score_adj_min` is unchanged even when `oom_score_adj` is modified.

It does make sense to put work that can be canceled/killed in an OOM situation into child processes with higher `oom_score_adj` values.  If an OOM situation does occur -- for example, on an embedded appliance --, the core service daemon has a much higher chance of surviving, even when the worker child processes are killed.  Of course, the core daemon itself should not be allocating dynamic memory in response to client requests, as any bug in it may not just crash that daemon, but bring the entire system to a halt (in an OOM situation where basically everything but the original cause, the core daemon, gets killed).

Comment: Regarding the statement that "using prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0) will allow a process with CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability (conveyed via e.g. filesystem capabilities) to modify the oom_score_adj of any other process" -- this is not quite correct. Only processes running under the same user can be tuned, not **any** other process

Comment: I might be nitpicking, but "The only "side effect" is that if the process is killed by a signal that causes a core dump, a core dump is actually generated." is not 100% correct either. Core dump is not necessarily generated, it *can* be generated, but is subject to the usual control mechanisms, like `ulimit`s

Comment: "a nefarious process only needs to do ten or eleven writes to /proc/self/oom_score_adj to make the OOM killer avoid it as much as possible" - can you elaborate please? How can a process go below the parent's `oom_score_adj_min`? If the parent has `-10` as score adjustment and the child inherits it and writes `-10` there once again, then the total adjustment won't be `-20`, it will still be `-10`

Comment: "If the new value is less than oom_score_adj_min, oom_score_adj_min is also set to the same value. There is no way to explicitly set, or raise, oom_score_adj_min. It can only be reduced. Therein lies the problem." -- this is not how it works, at least in the latest kernels (but I actually suspect that it works the same in all reasonably modern kernels). The `oom_score_adj_min` is *always* set to the `oom_score_adj` if the user has `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability, not only when it's lower. So a process can increase that limit if it has the capability.

Comment: So if a process with `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` sets `oom_score_adj` to 100 and then drops the capability (both effective and permitted) then it won't be able to set `oom_score_adj` to a value lower than 100

Comment: Thus making sure children can't make oom killer ignore them or treat unfairly is very simple. Fork, then change `oom_score_adj` to a value you want the child to have, then drop the capability, then `exec`.

Comment: @dvk: You have some good points, and I've reworded this correspondingly. (I did take a look at the kernel sources to be sure, of course.) The *"avoid as much as possible"* refers to the case where the parent increased `oom_score_adj` without CAP_SYS_RESOURCE, in which case the child starts with `oom_score_adj` > `oom_score_adj_min`, and it only takes ten or eleven writes in a binary search scheme for the child to lower its `oom_score_adj` = `oom_score_adj_min` it inherited.

Comment: @dvk: There are quite a few attacks that hinge on a privileged daemon forking a child in an unexpected situation, with the external nefarious party in control of that child. (For example, something like an unwary `wordexp()` without `WRDE_NOCMD` in the flags, and (parts of) the string to be expanded is from the client.) I would prefer a situation that *by default* makes the child processes more likely to be killed in an OOM situation than their parent, but the only way I can currently see how to do that ...

Comment: @dvk: ... is to run the parent as a dedicated user with tight `RLIMIT_NPROC`, switched to after forking a child process that will create any further children.  This is not really that strange to do, because e.g. Apache cgid does something very much like this to launch external CGI programs via such a child helper.  Anyway, thanks for the comments, and do let me know if there is something else you disagree with, so I can check and correct if necessary.