# go: cannot open and write /proc/os.Getpid()/oom_score_adj when I have the right capability as non-root user

Tags: linux, go

Firstly i read through this post: [Cannot open /proc/self/oom_score_adj when I have the right capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863306/cannot-open-proc-self-oom-score-adj-when-i-have-the-right-capability), thus get basic understanding that though it shows the current user as the owner of `oom_score_adj`, but the actual owner of this file is root, that is why i got this `panic: write /proc/8/oom_score_adj: permission denied` error.

Then i tried to follow the solution and invoke the `Prctl`: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Prctl to acquire the capability

```
if err := unix.Prctl(unix.PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 1, 0, 0, 0); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

The call doesn't panic, but still i got the `panic: write /proc/8/oom_score_adj: permission denied` error...

How should i achieve this in go? i mean changing my process's `oom_score_adj` to make it have a lower chance to be selected to be killed.

---

A bit more context: i have one main go process, and which will start a bunches of python worker processes in the runtime and communicate with them, the purpose of doing this is that having the oom killer to kill those python worker processes 1st when memory in pressure not the main go process, as if the main go process dies all python worker process has no meanings...

---

i got some trace logs with the `strace`, pls help to analyse what am i missing...

```
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "-100"], [/* 21 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x560665f45000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=36457, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 36457, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee7752000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\4\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1689360, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7faee7750000
mmap(NULL, 3795296, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee7199000
mprotect(0x7faee732e000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7faee752e000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x195000) = 0x7faee752e000
mmap(0x7faee7534000, 14688, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7faee7534000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7faee7751480) = 0
mprotect(0x7faee752e000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x560664a06000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7faee775b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7faee7752000, 36457)           = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x560665f45000
brk(0x560665f66000)                     = 0x560665f66000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=243, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 243, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee775a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26258, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7faee7753000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 23, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee7752000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 47, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=131, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 131, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=62, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 62, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=48, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 48, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=270, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 270, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee774a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1515838, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1515838, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee75d7000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2498, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2498, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee75d6000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=50, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 50, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee75d5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=198372, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 198372, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7faee75a4000
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(1, "-100\n", 5)                   = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
close(1)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "echo: ", 6)                   = 6
write(2, "write error", 11)             = 11
open("/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Permission denied", 19)     = 19
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```